# Как вывести отдельный SuggestView input для адреса в angular 9 Yandex API

Tags: yandex-maps-api, angular, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api

Возникла проблема с SuggestView конкретно в angular 9, так не совсем разбираюсь. Саму карту подключить смог, а вот вывести отдельный инпут не могу. Так же по туториалам смотрел как подключать и не сработало, а конкретно не может найти ymaps папку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
angular component

import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {ymaps} from '../../../../ymaps';

(window as any).global = window;

@Component({
 selector: 'create-training',
 styleUrls: ['./create-training.component.scss'],
 templateUrl: './create-training.component.html',
})


export class CreateTrainingComponent {
 public suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('input');
}

html код

<input type="text" id="input">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Вижу проблемы с импортом, это не связанно с либой, перепроверь что путь указан правильно.

```
import {ymaps} from '../../../../ymaps';
```

2) Код ниже нужно переместить в полифилы (по хорошему, хотя и так вероятно будет работать)
    (window as any).global = window;

3) `public suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('input');`
input ещё не отрендерится на этапе присвоения переменных, этот код в любом случае нужно перенести в ngAfterViewInit, то есть когда все элементы загружены

```
public suggestView;
...
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('input');
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, Валерий!